# How do I use GET in HTML5 Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, get

I want to display the *number* returned from this API: http://zhettoapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Values?product=Coca%20Cola

I want the number to be displayed in my HTML page.

But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Simply make an AJAX request to that URL. Many modern JavaScript libraries simplify that for you. For example, jQuery has a `$.get()` function, [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

Comment: jQeuery or ajax won't help here, the problem is a lack of CORS on the endpoint...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JQuery and do something like this:

```
$.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({type: "GET", url: "http://zhettoapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Values?product=Coca%20Cola", success: function (data) {
    window.alert("" + data);
    //example of setting innerHTML of object
    document.getElementById("yourelement").innerHTML = "The number is:" + data;
}, error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    // Display a generic error for now.
    alert("Error: " + xhr + "   " + status + "   " + error);
  }});
```

This will return your number in the variable data.  All you need to do is access your element within the success function and set the text to the number.

Comment: Thanks :D Btw, Is it the same method when using POST ?

Comment: No problem...and yes it is just change type: "POST".

Answer (score 0):

since the remote domain doesn't support CORS, you'll need to use your own "server-side proxy", or use a free one like yql:

very quickly and roughly:

```
<div id=d1></div>
<script>function paint(o){d1.innerHTML=o.query.results.row.col0;}</script>
<script src="https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fzhettoapi.azurewebsites.net%2Fapi%2FValues%3Fproduct%3DCoca%2520Cola%26callBack%3Ddd'%20&format=json&callback=paint"></script>
```